# Basic java - passing values to an object array

Tags: java, bufferedreader, object-oriented-analysis

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    staples[] stemp = new staples[8];
    int j;

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
            stemp[j].setName(reader.readLine());

            System.out.println("Enter your age : ");
            stemp[j].setAge(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            System.out.print("Employee number:" + "j:" + "name:" + stemp[j].getName() + " Age:" + stemp[j].getAge());
        }

        reader.close(); // VERY IMPORTANT TO CLOSE

        System.out.println("Program ended");
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error is " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass values to the the array object stemp which has two attributes name and age. What is the correct syntax to input the values to the array? Is the syntax above correct?

Comment: Does the code compile? If it compiles, it's syntaxically correct.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at employee.Employee.main(Employee.java:29)
Java Result: 1

Comment: What kind of type is "staples"?

Comment: So, you don't have a syntax problem, but a logic problem: you try to call a method on a null object. You never initialize any element of the array. Thta's what the exception says. Read it.

Comment: staples is a class . attributes string name and int age

Comment: isn't the  array initialization correct? forgive me , im new to java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `stemp[j] = new staples();`, otherwise you get NPE.

When you create an array in Java, JVM allocates space for `N` *references* to your objects, but not for the objects themselves. You need to allocate these one by one using the `new` operator.

```
for ( j=0;j<8;j++)
{
     stemp[j] = new staples();
     System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
     stemp[j].setName(reader.readLine());
     System.out.println("Enter your age : "); 
     stemp[j].setAge(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    staples[] stemp = new staples[8];
    int j;

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
            stemp[j] = new staples();
            stemp[j].setName(reader.readLine());

            System.out.println("Enter your age : ");
            stemp[j].setAge(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            System.out.print("Employee number:" + "j:" + "name:" + stemp[j].getName() + " Age:" + stemp[j].getAge());
        }

        reader.close(); // VERY IMPORTANT TO CLOSE

        System.out.println("Program ended");
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error is " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```